# A problem concerning the change of temperature and spectrum of a filament

Tags: optics, radiation, thermal-radiation

[image]

The spectrum of a filament has been given before, the left one having the lowest temperature, the middle with a medium temperature and the right one with the highest. My question is this: Why does the region of yellow light on the left have a small range of spectrum while the red and green ones both have a large range?

Also, why the temperature increasing results in the shrinking of red and green region and the expansion of yellow region? It seems strange that the continous wavelenth has different pattern.

Comment: That is a great question and a great observation!  I was reading this because I thought I could tell you the answer, then looked at the phenomena you are talking about and I hope to learn the answer here as well!

Comment: Do you have any idea how were obtained the spectra ?

Comment: Could be a crappy digital camera that does not reproduce colors properly? Or the color profile got changed somehow during editing?

Comment: I'm not able to see the picture. Could you upload it directly into the question?